# w3m Preformat output of website

Tags: unix, terminal, w3m

I want to use w3m a little bit more. However, when I try to use search engines like `w3m https://www.startpage.com/do/dsearch?query=test`, I get one screen of unnecessary links that I don't need. However, the search results I'm interessted in should be the only thing that I can see.

Is there a way to "preformat" the html file that w3m shows, so that I can do stuff like: If I go on site X, show me just the links corresponding the format `<a href=*>`, and don't show me anything else?

Answer (score 0):

I just started using w3m and had the same issue with viewing the stackexchange site (a whole page of links before the content). I made a mapping in my .wm3/keymap file like so:

```
# skip past all the cruft on the stack sites to where the question is asked     
keymap st COMMAND "WHEREIS Ask\ Question;  CENTER_V;  NEXT_HALF_PAGE"
```

It searches for the first useful piece of content, puts that in the centre of the screen, then scrolls up down half a page to get that part at the top. Maybe you can do something like that with the map commands?